# Avoid to much session variables from creation

Tags: asp.net

I am a beginner and I am not able to figure out the below scenario. I have a do databind() function in pageindexchanging event creates one more session on the server on page index change with gridview. As we are storing the source for the gridview in the session?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: protected void gvCktMap_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            gvCktMap.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;           
            gvCktMap.DataBind();
                              
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log.Warn("Logging:" + ex);

        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

Session is created once for each user. It means that if you store the grid data in session, you add the memory consumption with each new user.

There are other alternatives. If the data never changes or changes rarely, you can cache it in a shared container (httpcache, application). If the data varies for each user, do not cache it, read it from the database in each request.

Comment: hi wiktor,i wanted to know exactly how the grid will get the particular page on doing page index

Comment: If your concern is binding effectively then you should use the `ObjectDataSource` with paging. In any other case you have the whole data stored in your session and the grid is just picking a subset of the data to show the current page.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, can you give me an example regarding how to use objectdatasource control for paging because i haven't seen anything for the paging. thanks for your suggestion anyway

Comment: Hey wiktor, one more thing we are using ado.net not linq to sql for getting the data from the database. my question is still can i use object datasource control

Comment: No problem. Object data source works with any data source.

Comment: Hey wiktor, i found out some interesting things with objectdatasource control because of you thanks for that. But the interesting thing is to get a data of a particular page after googling i found that we have to change the stored procedure and have to pass page no as parameter in the procedure which i don't want to do. Can you suggest any way without changing the current procedure i want only the data that is related to the page using the procedure that is meant to return the whole data for the grid

Comment: You don't have to use the SP. You can write your own SQL query or make Linw2SQL create one for you.

Comment: you are right, i don't have the permission to change anything on the sqlserver.Can you suggest any other alternative

Comment: You don't have to change anything at the sql server side to call a SQL query from C#. Neither Linq2SQL doesn't really make you change anything in the database. You would really, really benefit from trying Linq2SQL, writing pages queries is just instant.

Comment: Hey wiktor sorry to bother you , i have few more things to ask you in every example i saw they are passing the starting row index number and maximum count for a page for the stored procedure. But i don't want to change the stored procedure but that doesn't accept both the parameters. In my case how can i achieve the paging.

Comment: can i acheive by simply calling the stored procedure. Is it going to work fine in my case. Main aim of mine is to retain the object data source control property is not to load the whole grid it has to load only the page on the grid that i want or the users want. But i am in kind of doubt about to specify the start for the page and no.of rows in the page.

Comment: The control (gridview, listview) passes the information about the current page and the page size to the object data source and then the object data source passes it automatically to the data source. Study any example, the first pick from google http://samsalisbury.net/articles/objectdatasource-listview-paging-minimal-example/

Comment: Hey wiktor, I have a question for you regarding storage of gridview into dataset. Can you give a sample code regarding the storage of gridview into dataset.